# Keeping the latest erlang but running riak's make devrel

Tags: erlang, riak

I'm reading this tutorial:
http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.1.4/tutorials/fast-track/Building-a-Development-Environment/

I installed riak from the .deb package in ubuntu. If I run `riak start` it will say "node is already running!" the second time I do it. I downloaded the riak source. The tutorial wants me to do `make devrel`. It gives me a long erlang error. I think I need to compile from source first before I can run that. if I try to compile riak from source it will complain I have the latest version of erlang. I tried to `alias erl=/usr/lib/riak/erts-5.9.1/bin/erl` to use the older version bundled with riak but it still gives same error. I tried to remove the vsn requirements from the rebar.config.

Is there a way to run multiple nodes using `riak start` after installing riak from the .deb package? Is there a way to compile riak without removing the latest version of erlang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem with Riak installed under Homebrew.

The easiest thing is to use [Kerl](https://github.com/spawngrid/kerl) to install multiple versions of Erlang/OTP, then build Riak from source with the `devrel` target.  You can find the instructions for getting the Erlang installation right at Basho's docs on [installing Erlang using Kerl](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.1.4/tutorials/installation/Installing-Erlang/#Install-using-kerl).

`make devrel` will get you multiple complete, self-contained instances of Riak.